# Trying to get GUI to print random card in deck using arrayList

Tags: java, random, arraylist, javafx

So I'm currently working on a Card War Game in java. I'm trying to get the GUI screen to print 2 random cards from a set of card images using an arrayList (must use this for assignment). The card image files are named 1.png,2.png,...52.png and stored in a image/card directory. My question is how do I get two cards to appear randomly? Thanks here's my code

Also, just to note, I'm a relatively new programmer

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardWar extends Application{

public static void main(String args[]){
Application.launch(args);


}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){


ArrayList<Integer> cardList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 1; i <=52;i++){
cardList.add(i);
}


java.util.Collections.shuffle(cardList);
System.out.println(cardList.get(0));




//Label label1 = new Label ("Welcome to the Card War Game!");

//layout for first scene
StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
Button welcome = new Button("Click to Play");
Text text1 = new Text(20,20, "Welcome to The Game");
layout1.getChildren().add(welcome);



//layout for second scene
//Button button2 = new Button("You are here!");
Pane layout2 = new HBox (457);
//layout2.getChildren().add(button2);
Image image = new Image("image/card/1.png");
Image image2 = new Image("image/card/2.png");

ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
imageView2.setFitWidth(100);

layout2.getChildren().add(new ImageView (image));
layout2.getChildren().add(new ImageView (image2));



Scene scene = new Scene (layout1,600,300);
Scene scene2 = new Scene(layout2,600,300);

welcome.setOnAction(e -> primaryStage.setScene(scene2));

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setTitle("War Game");
primaryStage.show();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified version of your code. This is what you should do:

- create a dedicated Card class, an object which you can use. Don't use integers
- load the cards into a list (the deck). The cards are loaded only once
- create the stock, i. e. a list out of the deck which you can modify
- shuffle the stock
- put stock on the table
- pick a card from the stock and add it to the tableau until there are no more cards available in the stock

The code:

```
public class CardWar extends Application {

    /**
     * List of all available cards. Loaded once at game start.
     */
    List<Card> deck;

    /**
     * List of cards in the game.
     */
    List<Card> stock;

    /**
     * Cards to be dealt
     */
    Pane stockPane;

    /**
     * Cards which are already dealt
     */
    FlowPane tableauPane;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // load all cards into a list
        loadCards();

        // create playfield: table with toolbar
        BorderPane playfield = new BorderPane();
        playfield.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");

        // simple flowpane to align one card next to the other 
        FlowPane tableauPane = new FlowPane();

        // pick 2 cards and add them to the table
        Button button = new Button( "Pick Cards");
        button.setOnAction( e -> {

            // abort if we don't have cards in the deck
            if( stock.size() == 0)
                return;

            Card card;

            // pick top card and add it to the table
            card = stock.remove( stock.size()-1);
            stockPane.getChildren().remove(card);
            tableauPane.getChildren().add(card);

            // pick top card and add it to the table
            card = stock.remove( stock.size()-1);
            stockPane.getChildren().remove(card);
            tableauPane.getChildren().add(card);

        });

        playfield.setCenter(tableauPane);

        // talon contains all cards of the deck
        stockPane = new Pane();
        playfield.setBottom(stockPane);

        // toolbar with a button
        HBox toolbar = new HBox();
        toolbar.getChildren().add( button);

        playfield.setTop(toolbar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(playfield, 1600, 900, Color.GREEN);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("War Game");
        primaryStage.show();

        // create deck for game, shuffle cards
        startGame();

    }

    private void startGame() {

        // create stock from deck
        stock = new ArrayList<>( deck);

        // shuffle stock
        Collections.shuffle(stock);

        // put cards on stock pane
        for( int i=0; i < stock.size(); i++) {

            // get card from stock
            Card card = stock.get(i);

            // set card position
            card.setLayoutX(i * 20);

            // put card on stock pane
            stockPane.getChildren().add( card);

        }
    }

    private void loadCards() {

        deck = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 52; i++) {
            deck.add( new Card( i));
        }
    }

    private static class Card extends ImageView {

        public Card( int id) {

            setImage(new Image( getClass().getResource("image/card/" + id + ".png").toExternalForm()));

            setFitHeight(100);
            setFitWidth(100);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Collections.shuffle(...)` method to shuffle the `ArrayList`.

Then just take the first two entries from the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing but I'm not sure how to get it to call those two entries

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I don't understand your problem then.

Comment: I have to print an image of two random cards from a deck of 52 image files and I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Again, I'm not sure what you are asking.  You already seem to have code that loads two hardcoded images. So you would just modify the code to create the image filename based on the value from the first two entries in the ArrayList.

Comment: Or put the images in a List or Map

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new list like this using .subList(fromIndex, toIndex)

```
ArrayList list2= new ArrayList(
<your list>.subList(0,1))
```