# Can't Get Program To Recognize Card Values

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, javafx, logic

My program won't go inside of this block of code

```
if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3))
               {
                  if(express == 24){
                     display.setText("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     display.setText("Incorrect");

               }
```

I think it is because I am trying to get the card value of `card1` when the cards that are appearing are just random cards out of my deck. What could I use to evaluate the new cards that appear? Here is my full code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");

      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);


      HBox center = new HBox(10);
      Card card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);

      Card card3 = new Card(deck.get(3));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);

      Card card4 = new Card(deck.get(4));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);



      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
               Collections.shuffle(deck);
              center.getChildren().clear();    
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(2)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));

            });





      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();


      int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : -1;      



     // expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      bottom.getChildren().add(expression);
      bottom.getChildren().add(tfExpress);
      bottom.getChildren().add(btVerify);

      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> 
            {
               LinkedList<Character> expInput = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c: tfExpress.getText().toCharArray()){
                expInput.add(c);
                }

               expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));


               if(card1.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == (int)expInput.get(3))
               {
                  if(express == 24){
                     display.setText("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     display.setText("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  display.setText("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });



      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         getChildren().add(new ImageView(cardImage));
         cardVal = card;

      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }




   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the character value of a number with an integer value. Those don't match. To make this visually clear:

```
String numbers = "0123456789";
for(char c: numbers.toCharArray()){
  System.out.println( c);
}
```

produces

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

But if you cast the character value to an integer like you do in your program, you'll get this

> 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57

Which are the ascii values of your characters.

In other words: For the character "1" and card value 1 you are comparing if 1 == 49.

Solution: You need to parse the characters instead of casting them to int, e. g. using

```
Character.getNumericValue(...)
```

*As a general note: The easiest way to find out what's wrong with your code is to use a debugger. Alternatively a simple logging output would show you what's wrong.*

---

Edit: fyi, you have a bug:

```
int i = 1;
while(i < 52){
  deck.add(i);
  i++;
}
```

will result in the last card being lost.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. So my new block of code is: 'if(card1.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(3))` and it is running the same as before. My guess is this is because of what I was stating before, it doesn't know that the cards shown have numeric values. Any advice on how to link this? And I think I know what to do about the deck.

Comment: Just a general hint. Look at my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993613/trying-to-get-gui-to-print-random-card-in-deck-using-arraylist/29998568#29998568). And if you really give them numbers, take a look at the [modulo operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html). It saves you from doing the subtractions and reduces your code.

Comment: o wow this is great! So you're probably suggesting that I change the way I create my deck because right now it is only getting random integer values, not the actual value of the cards. Going to make this change. I foresee that I will still probably have an issue evaluating the expression that the user inputs though.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Roland09/e00f7e97852c9113877b). Especially the enum Rank. That's where you would give the cards a value.

Comment: Yes I've seen this it is brilliant. I just feel like it's a lot for what I'm trying to do. I think on a larger scale program I would want to have a more interactive deck, but for this I'm wanting to keep my code fairly condensed.

Comment: You don't have to use all of that code. Just use your Card class with the Suit enum and the Rank enum. And extend the Rank enum by a value attribute in which you define your card value.