# Setting Numeric Values to Card Values

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, integer, character

here is what I have now:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.*;

public class Main extends Application {


   private Card card1;
   private Card card2;
   private Card card3;
   private Card card4;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


      ArrayList<Integer> deck;
      deck = new ArrayList<>();
      int i = 1;
      while(i < 52){
         deck.add(i);
         i++;
      }
      final AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>("go.");

      Collections.shuffle(deck);

      BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

      HBox top = new HBox(10);
      Label display = new Label(result.toString());
      Button btShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");

      top.getChildren().add(display);
      top.getChildren().add(btShuffle);




      HBox center = new HBox(10);

      card1 = new Card(deck.get(0));
      center.getChildren().add(card1);

      Card card2;
      card2 = new Card(deck.get(1));
      center.getChildren().add(card2);


      card3 = new Card(deck.get(3));
      center.getChildren().add(card3);


      card4 = new Card(deck.get(4));
      center.getChildren().add(card4);



      btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
                  center.getChildren().clear();  
                   Collections.shuffle(deck);


              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(4)));

            });





      HBox bottom = new HBox(10);
      Label expression = new Label("Please Enter the expression: ");

      TextField tfExpress = new TextField();
      ArrayList<Character> signs = new ArrayList<>();
      signs.add('/');
      signs.add('+');
      signs.add('(');
      signs.add(')');
      signs.add('-');
      signs.add('^');
      signs.add('*');
      signs.add('%');
      String str = tfExpress.getText();


      int express = (str != null && !"".equals(str)) ? Integer.parseInt(str) : 0;      



     // expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

      Button btVerify = new Button("Verify");
      bottom.getChildren().add(expression);
      bottom.getChildren().add(tfExpress);
      bottom.getChildren().add(btVerify);

      btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> 
            {
               LinkedList<Character> expInput = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c: tfExpress.getText().toCharArray()){
                expInput.add(c);
                }
            String[] inputIntegers = tfExpress.getText().split("[^0-9]+");

               expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String s:inputIntegers)
            {
               temp.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(s)));
            } 
            temp.remove(new Integer(card1.CardValue()));
            temp.remove(new Integer(card2.CardValue()));                    
            temp.remove(new Integer(card3.CardValue()));          
            temp.remove(new Integer(card4.CardValue()));          


               if(temp.isEmpty() /*card1.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(deck.get(0))
               && card2.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(deck.get(1))
               && card3.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(deck.get(2))
               && card4.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(deck.get(3))*/)
               {
                  if(express == 24){
                     display.setText("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     display.setText("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  display.setText("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });



      pane.setTop(top);
      pane.setCenter(center);
      pane.setBottom(bottom);

      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      primaryStage.setTitle("24 card game");
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();
   }



   public class Card extends Pane {
      public int cardVal;
      Card(int card){
         Image cardImage;
         cardImage = new Image("card/"+ card +".png");
         getChildren().add(new ImageView(cardImage));
         cardVal = card;

      }

      public int CardValue(){
         int card = 0;

         if(cardVal <= 13){
            card = cardVal;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 13 && cardVal <= 26){
            card = cardVal - 13;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 26 && cardVal <= 39){
            card = cardVal - 26;
         }
         else if(cardVal > 39 && cardVal <= 52){
            card = cardVal - 39;
         }


         return card;
      }




   }



   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```

In my:

```
 btShuffle.setOnAction(
            e -> {
                  center.getChildren().clear();  
                   Collections.shuffle(deck);


              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(0)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(1)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(3)));
              center.getChildren().add(new Card(deck.get(4)));

            });
```

I want to change these values to card1-4, but when I do this it will not shuffle now. Does anybody know why this is? Also, I did a Scanner and determined that the card values are in fact being assigned to the cards correctly it's just a matter of correctly evaluating them now.

Comment: Only give the relevant code! :-)

Comment: Well I guess that would be this block: if(card1.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(0)
               && card2.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(1)
               && card3.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(2)
               && card4.CardValue() == Character.getNumericValue(3)) but I'm not exactly sure because I believe that is evaluating the numbers I am entering, the cards just don't actually have values.

Comment: I see. I'll try to edit your post to remove non-relevant code, do not hesitate to remove or add more!

Comment: Why are you using `Character.getNumericValue`? You can just use the value itself e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Thank you, do you think you could help me find the root of my issue by doing so @Docteur?

Comment: @deyur What do you mean by this?

Comment: As deyur pointed out, I don't understand the usage of `Character.getNumericValue()` either. Anyways, you are starting your loop to add numbers to your deck at `i == 1`. You then create your first card with this value, so `CardValue()` will return `1` and obviously `1 != 0`.

Comment: @Jyr ah, I see. For some reason when I start at 0 I am getting a run-time error. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: Edit your question to include the description of the run-time error and on which line it occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but it seems like you are assuming that `card1 == 0`, `card2 == 1`, etc. This wouldn't be true because you are initializing your cards from the deck, which you set up to start from 1. You should start your deck from 0 to get the desired effect (Currently you only have 51 cards in the deck).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
     deck.add(i);
 }
```

**EDIT:** The reason that you are getting the error with `card2` is because you are declaring it locally within the same method as your lambda call (the `start()` method). Delete the statement: `Card card2;` from within your `start()` method and it should work.

Comment: I keep getting a run-time error when trying to use this for loop instead. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @JohnDoe What kind of run-time error are you getting?

Comment: @JohnDoe What do you mean when you say that "it will not shuffle now?"

Comment: The shuffle button will not change card values if I replace deck.get(0) with card1. But I feel I need to do this because my Verify button cannot read the values of the cards after they have been shuffled.

Comment: @JohnDoe Have you tried actually reassigning the values for `card1`? Maybe try putting `card1 = new Card(deck.get(0))` after the sort and then changing the following line to `center.getChildren().add(card1)`

Comment: So this is interesting, I just tried this and it works fine for card1, but I then get an error for card2. The error is: Main.java:83: error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final. This is strange, why would it work for the first card but not the others?

Comment: This is like fixing yet another hole in a barrel which has lots of holes.

Comment: @Roland I am just trying to answer the question that he is asking, not write the code for him. It is his job to make mistakes and just copying somebody else's completed code won't teach him anything.

Comment: @camelsaucerer: I know, but it's not his first problem with his card game. And it won't be his last from the looks of it. Unfortunately he's refusing to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your other question you mentioned you wanted to keep your code "condensed". Please, don't do that. You should realize by now that your "condensed" code leads you to a lot of problems which brought you here.

Here's a better example for you:

- create a Suit enum with a name
- create a Rank enum with a name and a value or whatever other attributes you have
- create a card class which consists of Suit and Rank and which loads the image depending on the names (yes, you have to rename the images properly)
- create your cards by iterating through all combinations of Suit and Rank

There's not much else to it. Here's the code:

```
public class CardsDemo extends Application {

    /**
     * All the cards in the game. Loaded only once at game start.
     */
    private List<Card> deck;

    /**
     * The cards to be dealt. Created initially from the deck.
     */
    private List<Card> stock;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // create cards
        deck = createDeck();

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        stock = new ArrayList<>( deck);

        // shuffle cards
        Collections.shuffle(stock);

        // deal cards
        while( !stock.isEmpty()) {

            Card card = stock.remove(0);

            System.out.println( "Dealing: " + card);
        }

    }

    private List<Card> createDeck() {

        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for( Suit suit: EnumSet.allOf(Suit.class)) {

            for( Rank rank: EnumSet.allOf( Rank.class)) {

                Card card = new Card( suit, rank);
                cards.add( card);
            }

        }

        return cards;

    }

    public static class Card {
        Suit suit;
        Rank rank;

        public Card( Suit suit, Rank rank) {
            this.suit = suit;
            this.rank = rank;

            // TODO: create imageview
            String filename = "card/" + suit.getName() + "_" + rank.getName() + ".png";

            System.out.println( "Filename: " + filename);

        }

        public Suit getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public Rank getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Suit: " + suit + ", Rank: " + rank + ", Value: " + rank.getValue(); 
        }
    }

    public enum Rank {

        ACE( "A", 1),
        _2( "2", 2),
        _3("3", 3),
        _4("4", 4),
        _5("5", 5),
        _6("6", 6),
        _7("7", 7),
        _8("8", 8),
        _9("9", 9),
        _10("10", 10),
        JACK("J", 11),
        QUEEN("Q", 12),
        KING("K", 13)
        ;

        String name;
        int value;

        Rank( String name, int value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public enum Suit {

        SPADES( "spade"),
        HEARTS( "heart"),
        CLUBS( "club"),
        DIAMONDS("diamond"),
        ;

        String name;

        Suit( String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And [this question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993613/trying-to-get-gui-to-print-random-card-in-deck-using-arraylist/29998568#29998568) about how to deal cards. You don't use "get", instead use "remove" for accessing the cards. Simply using "get" will only give you the same card over and over again. You need to remove it as well. However, remove also gives you the removed card, so remove is sufficient.

Comment: I understand this a much better way to implement my cards but it's just not the issue I'm having at the moment. If there is help in other areas you could provide it would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, I won't, it's just a waste of time. The next problem you'll be facing is when you'll notice that you are not having all the cards in the game. And then that you are dealing the same cards over and over again, even though it doesn't look like it initially, because you're shuffling them. The cards you deal are just random values, always from the same pool which contains already dealt cards.

Comment: Roland, this is not a card game in which any cards are to be dealt. The purpose of this game is for the user to enter an expression of numeric values that equals 24. All the cards are there for is to represent those numeric values. The values are 1-13 or Ace-King respectively. Four cards appear, and the user enters an expression according to those cards. The game does not end, the shuffle button should always work. Does this make sense?